# cakephp query apply has many conditions run time

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

help me to create query in cakephp

```
Table 
users
id name
1  jaskaran
2  jaswinder
3  here


Games
id games
1  chess
2  criket
3  hokey
4  other

user_games
user_id game_id
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       4
3       2
2       1
```

now in user model i have apply  hasMany with user_games

now any user search with user name and game like
where name="%jas%" and game_id =1

```
$this->User->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('user.name like'=>'%jas%','Game.game_id'=>1)));
```

my Game.game_id condition is not working property. how can i apply this one ?

Comment: "is not working properly" as in you get an error or it just doesn't filter? Are those models containable?

Comment: yes it not filter records accounting my where conditions

Comment: you can debug with <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?> in your View and see the exact query.

Comment: Paulo Rodrigues give me wrong ans :(

Comment: Show the model relationship please

Comment: ok

Class User extends AppModel {

var $hasMany = array('UserGame');
}

Comment: you modify the model name of UserGames to UserGame or is a typo error?

Comment: your actual query run?? if yes paste the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition need filter by **Game.id**, not **Game.game_id**, you don't have field **game_id** in model **Game**.

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.name LIKE' => '%jas%', 'Game.id' => 1)));
```

Comment: I have apply has many with user_game not games table please review my query first it wrong ans

Comment: Ok, but from the description of your tables, the relationship seems to be HABTM. You're right that the relationship you want to do is `hasMany`?